# Changing System Date time makes WCF channel faulted

Tags: wcf, security, netnamedpipebinding

I have an application which uses custom binding (netnamedpipe transport) to communicate to the service. When I change System time, it makes WCF channel faulted. It throws internally ReceiveTimeout excepetion when we change system time which makes channel faulted.

I tried to set clock skew parameter of the binding but it throws invalid operation exception.

```
 <security>
        <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="10.00:07:00" />
        <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="10.00:07:00" />
        <secureConversationBootstrap>
          <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="10.00:30:00" />
          <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="10.00:30:00" />
        </secureConversationBootstrap>
      </security>
      <namedPipeTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
```

Does WCF have any other parameter to avoid this problem with netnamed pipe transport?

Comment: did you updated both server and client configs?

Comment: yes, I updated both the files.